# Jenkins Running xUnit Tests Code 58

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, continuous-integration, xunit

This has me completely stumped.  I have a Jenkins build configured to run some xUnit tests in my solution via an MSBuild script.

When it gets to the task to run the tests I get a failure message:

error MSB3073: The command .... exited with code 58.

I can't even find any info on what error code 58 is.

If I copy the command to a CMD window and run it it runs perfectly so the command itself is definitely correct.  Any ideas what error code 58 is?  Or has anyone seen this problem before and have a solution?

Comment: So what is the actual error message. It might help to just ignore the exit code itself.